# отличать двузначное число от однозначного в python строке

Tags: python, python-3.x

надо написать цикл, который при проходе по этой строке 'a3b4c2e10b1' сможет отличить 10 от 1 и 0.
я уже пробовал проходиться по индексам, но на последнем элементе, выдает ошибку, что цикл вне строки, потому что проверяет значение которого нет - то есть выход за строку.

Comment: Чеееегоооо?????

Comment: пример цикла можно? и задачу, которую он должен выполнить. А то ощущения, как и предыдущий комментарий

Comment: в задаче надо отличать буквы от цифр

Comment: for i in  range(len(n)):
    if n[i] in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
        c=n[i]
    else:
        if n[i+1] not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            m=int(n[i]+(n[i+1]))
        else:
            m=int(n[i])

Comment: Уточните формат строки, числа всегда идут после букв/слов? Приведите несколько примеров входных и выходных данных короче

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив туда код из комментария

Answer (score 2):

Используйте регулярные выражения - это проще всего

#### Вариант 1

```
>>> import re
>>> res = re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z])*(\d*)", 'a3b4c2e10b1')
>>> res
[('a', '3'), ('b', '4'), ('c', '2'), ('e', '10'), ('b', '1'), (' ', ' ')]
>>> letters, digits = [a[0] for a in res if a[0]], [a[1] for a in res if a[1]] 
>>> letters
['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'b']
>>> digits
['3', '4', '2', '10', '1']
```

UPD: теперь регулярке плевать, в каком порядке идут буквы и цифры, но приходится избавляться от пустых значений некрасиво, оптимизацию оставляю вам)

#### Вариант 2

```
>>> a = "a3b4c2e10b1"
>>> digits = list(filter(None, re.split("[a-zA-Z]+", a)))
>>> letters = list(filter(None, re.split("\d+", a)))
```

Comment: Вместо `letters, digits = [a[0] for a in res], [a[1] for a in res]` лучше `letters, digits = zip(*res)` написать

Comment: Можно сделать проще и искать только по паттерну `"\d*"`, так как интересуют только числа, как я понимаю

Comment: возможно, из вопроса не очевидно это, поэтому я просто быстро сделала регулярку, которая все найдет)